# ssh to nginx loadbalancer with python

Tags: python, authentication, nginx

Hello I am new to programming/scripting. My current focus in on network automation. Im wanting to know some recommended packages while using python to authenticate (SSH) to a nginx loadbalancer on linux.
thank you. I was thinking paramiko would be a good choice.